# Html.BeginForm does not call action method in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a partial view:

```
@model MsmStore.Domain.Products

<h3 class="lead">
    @Model.Name
</h3>
@*        <img src="~/images/MainLogo.jpg"/>*@
<p>
    @Model.Decription
</p>
<p>
    @Model.Price
</p>

@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateBasketSummary", "Order", new { ProductID = Model.ID }))
{
    @Html.Hidden("ProductID", Model.ID)
    <input type="button" value="Click" />
}
```

this Html.BeginForm does not call action method (UpdateBasketSummary).

and this is my Action Method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult UpdateBasketSummary(string ProductID)
    {
//          orderRepository.AddToCart(ProductID, 1);
            return PartialView("BasketSummary", ProductID);
    }
```

this is my routing code:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(null, "{controller}/{action}");
```

Comment: You need to do both bellow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An input with type button will not submit the form, by default.  You need to change it to

```
 <input type="submit" value="click" />
```

or

```
<button type="submit" value="click" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Input of type button will not post your form, replace it with..

```
<input type="submit" value="Click" />
```

Answer (score 0):

please, try this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateBasketSummary", "Order"))
{
    @Html.Hidden("ProductID", Model.ID)
   <input type="button" value="Click" />
}

[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult UpdateBasketSummary(int ProductID)
{
   //orderRepository.AddToCart(ProductID, 1);
   return PartialView("BasketSummary", ProductID);
}
```

btw. not need to send `ProductID` in `BeginForm`, as you already did it by `Hidden field`

**Edited:** due to @Ben Griffiths answer:
you also need to change `type='button'` to `type='submit'` of course

Answer (score 0):

Your action requires the http method POST and yet your beginForm call does not set the http method to POST.  Without explicitly setting the http method you will be forced to use the default, which is a GET.